# Have BootStrap buttons fill the height of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple web page that will have three large buttons that should fill the entire page (ie, they span the width of the page, and should take up 33.3% of the height for each.) I have the width part working, but I am unsure how to get the heights part working. This is my code so far.

```
<html>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <span style="font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="https://encore.mpl.on.ca/iii/mobile/homepage?lang=eng" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary"><i class = "fa fa-search fa-3x"></i>  &nbsp<h1>Catalogue Search</h1></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="https://encore.mpl.on.ca/iii/mobile/homepage/Sdologin?lang=eng&loginReason=doDefault" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info"><i class = "fa fa-sign-in fa-3x"></i> &nbsp<h1>Library Account Login</h1></button></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="http://www.mpl.on.ca/hours.php" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger"><i class = "fa fa-map-marker fa-3x"></i>  &nbsp<h1>Hours and Locations</h1></button></a>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You haven't specified whether you are using Bootstrap v3 or v4.
2. You should only be using `.col-*-*` as children of `.row` elements or any other elements with a default `margin: 0 -15px` (such as `.form-group`s).
3. You are using `.col-*-4` when you don't want your element to be 1/3 of their parent width.
4. You're using 3 `<h1>` tags on the same page, which is a very big ***no-no*** SEO-wise.

Probably the easiest way to achieve what you want, using Bootstrap v3 (which is what I assume you're using), would be using a `.btn-block` combined with `flexbox`. Please also note I've made significant changes to markup (yours is invalid).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div.jumbotron {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.jumbotron > .btn-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  align-items: stretch;
}
.jumbotron > .btn-block > .btn {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .jumbotron > .btn-block {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group btn-block">
          <a href="https://encore.mpl.on.ca/iii/mobile/homepage?lang=eng" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary"><i class = "fa fa-search fa-3x"></i><h1>Catalogue Search</h1></a>
          <a href="https://encore.mpl.on.ca/iii/mobile/homepage/Sdologin?lang=eng&loginReason=doDefault" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info"><i class = "fa fa-sign-in fa-3x"></i><h1>Library Account Login</h1></a>
          <a href="http://www.mpl.on.ca/hours.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger"><i class = "fa fa-map-marker fa-3x"></i><h1>Hours and Locations</h1></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Don't forget to [`autoprefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.  I spent an hour with the CSS on the same page and having it not work for me. Once i moved the CSS to its own page things began to work.

Answer (score 1):

The following fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/AshokBasarakod/5vxfetpg/1/) may solve your problem.

Codes are as follows:
HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <button id="catalogSearch" class="btn btn-default">Catalogue Search </button>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" id = "AccountLogin" class="btn btn-default">Library Account Login</button>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="row">
        <button id ="hrsLocations" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">  Hours and Locations</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn 
{
  width:100%;
  padding: 12%; 
}
```

JavsScript

```
document.getElementById("catalogSearch").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "https://encore.mpl.on.ca/iii/mobile/homepage?lang=eng";
   };

document.getElementById("AccountLogin").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "https://encore.mpl.on.ca/iii/mobile/homepage/Sdologin?lang=eng&loginReason=doDefault";
    };

document.getElementById("hrsLocations").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "http://www.mpl.on.ca/hours.php";
    };
```

Comment: [It would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of 
the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You make the jsfiddle link clickable (act as a hyperlink) by using the following formats described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)

Comment: @LibinVarghese Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this without bootstrap :)
// this will call the button and design

```
.button {
    background-color: gray;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    margin:10px
}

  // this will assign sizes of the button you want
.btnbig {
    width: 99%;
    height: 500px;
}

  //btnbig is the class of your button you want to modify

<div class="button btnbig">A big button</div>
```

is this clear now ? im sorry (Im newbie)

Comment: Try this is not a proper approach to give an answer. Please provide a good description as well for your code.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly then you can use CSS calc to set the height as a percentage of the page.

```
.btn-block {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: calc(100vh/3);
}
```